# How to create a " box with arrow edges in the bottom and placing textinput under the arrow edges" using css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

1. As Im new to HTML and CSS, facing difficulties in creating the box arrow edges at the bottom.
2. I have 4 div's in that i have created a box for 1st div,  but i don't know how to make arrow edges at the bottom.
3. Expected Output:

[image: List item]

4. The output I got :

[image]

5.The code:

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.bx--row {
  display: flex;

  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: -1rem;
  margin-left: -1rem;
}
.bx--col {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
.all-style{
  height: 2rem;
    background-color: #12619d;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
   
}
```

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="bx--row keyword-labels">
          <div className="bx--col all-style">
          
              <label>All</label>
             
           
          </div>
          <div className="bx--col">
            <label>Drug</label>
          </div>
          <div className="bx--col">
            <label>Disease</label>
          </div>
          <div className="bx--col">
            <label>Toxicology</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
              <input type="text" />
              </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

add this styles to your css

```css
.bx-col {
    position: relative;
}
.bx-col:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border-top: 5px solid #12619d;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: If you want the arrow at the top you can use this code:
```.bx-col:after {
              position: absolute;
              content: '';
              border-bottom: 10px solid #8e77f3;
              border-left: 10px solid transparent;
              border-top: 10px solid transparent;
              border-right: 10px solid transparent;
              top: 0%;
              left: 50%;
              transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
              display: block;
            }```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *psuedo* css `:after` on active element, styling the borders of the *psuedo* element. Set the content to empty. Make the top border the color of the background of your button and make the color of the other borders opaque using rgba(red, green, blue, alpha) with an alpha of `0`. This will make the top border the only one seen. Make the height of your psuedo element twice the size of the top border.

Also style the `:after` element with `position: absolute;` so you can control its ***top*** position in relation to the parent element which will have (***position: relative***). Lastly position `after` element so it is just below the `active` element by setting a class `active` to the targeted element, then set the psuedo `:after` to the `.active` class, `.active:after {`.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  padding: 2px 7px;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: #12619d;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 3.5px;
}

li.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 7.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-right: 7.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 7.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-top: 7.5px solid #12619d;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  top: 2.2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">All</li>
    <li>Drug</li>
    <li>Diesease</li>
    <li>Toxicolgy</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```